# Estoy tratando de ordenar vectores de un mismo numero

Tags: c

Estoy practicando para dar un examen final y no se como encarar de unos de los puntos que nos dio el profesor para ir practicando, esto dice así:

- Realice una función que calcule y retorne cual es la HORA del día en el que salen la mayor cantidad de micros (int).

Por ejemplo si un micro parte a las 7:30 y otro a las 7:50, ya tenemos dos micros que parten a las 7

[image: Aqui les adjunto el enunciado, los demas puntos los tengo todos resueltos]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 4

struct horario{
    int horas;
    int minutos;

};

struct micro{
    struct horario partida;
    char origen[50];
    char destino[50];
    int pasajes_vendidos;
};

void ordenar_salida(struct horario salida[], int n);

int main(){
    struct horario salida[N];
    struct micro micros[N];
    int i;

    
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        fflush(stdin);
        
        printf("\n\tIngrese origen: ");
        gets(micros->origen);
        
        printf("\n\tIngrese destino: ");
        gets(micros->destino);
        
        printf("\n\tIngrese pasajes vendidos: ");
        scanf("%d",&micros[i].pasajes_vendidos);
    
        printf("\n\tDigite hora salida: ");
        scanf("%d", &salida[i].horas);
    }
    ordenar_salida(salida,N);
    
    return 0;
}

void ordenar_salida(struct horario salida[], int n){

    int i, j, aux1;
    struct horario aux;
    
    // Mostrar datos
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("\n\tHoras ingresadas: %d",salida[i].horas);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n-1;j++){
            if(salida[j].horas > salida[j+1].horas){
                aux = salida[j];
                salida[j] = salida[j+1];
                salida[j+1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("\n\t%d",salida[i].horas);
    }

}


int mayor_salida(struct horario salida[], int n){
    
    int i, j, aux1;
    struct horario aux;
    int cant_salida;
    
    
    
    
}
```

Lo que no consigo de momento es hacer el punto 2, pense en hacer un bucle y guardar cada danto dentro de un arreglo.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 4

struct horario{
    int horas;
    int minutos;

};

struct micro{
    struct horario partida;
    char origen[50];
    char destino[50];
    int pasajes_vendidos;
};

void ordenar_salida(struct horario salida[], int n);
void mayor_salida(struct horario salida[], int n);


int main(){
    struct horario salida[N];
    struct micro micros[N];
    int i;

    
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        fflush(stdin);
        
        printf("\n\tIngrese origen: ");
        gets(micros[i].origen);
        
        printf("\n\tIngrese destino: ");
        gets(micros[i].destino);
        
        printf("\n\tIngrese pasajes vendidos: ");
        scanf("%d",&micros[i].pasajes_vendidos);
    
        printf("\n\tDigite hora salida: ");
        scanf("%d", &salida[i].horas);
    }
    ordenar_salida(salida,N);
    mayor_salida(salida, N);
    

    
    return 0;
    }

 

    void ordenar_salida(struct horario salida[], int n){

    int i, j, aux1;
    struct horario aux;
    
    // Mostrar datos
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("\n\tHoras ingresadas: %d",salida[i].horas);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n-1;j++){
            if(salida[j].horas > salida[j+1].horas){
                aux = salida[j];
                salida[j] = salida[j+1];
                salida[j+1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("\n\t%d",salida[i].horas);
    }

}
```

Comment: tengo todos los puntos resultos menos el segundo que no se como encararlo

Comment: Por favor añade lo que has intentado, así podremos ayudarte. Aquí no hacemos tareas y por ello puede que tu pregunta sea cerrada, a menos que añadas lo que has intentado y expliques el problema que tienes

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` no debería servirte de nada. Lo que sí deberías hacer es consumir el salto de línea que deja el `scanf`. Puedes hacerlo con `getchar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sabiendo que un día tiene una cantidad determinada y fija de horas, prepara una formación<sup>1</sup> con 24 posiciones en que hagas el recuento:

```
int recuento[24] = {}; // Todos los elementos inicializados a cero.
```

Después podrás sumar apariciones en cada hora:

```
for (int indice = 0; indice < N; ++indice){
    ++recuento[salida[i].horas];
}
```

Una vez hecho eso, buscas cuál es el índice con el valor más grande:

```
int mayor = 0;
for (int hora = 0; hora < 14; ++hora){
    if (recuento[mayor] < recuento[hora])
        mayor = hora;
}
```

Y ya estaría:

```
printf("La hora con más micros es %d, con un total de %d micros\n", mayor, recuento[mayor]);
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta pero no me estaria dando los valores correctos, voy a seguir probando mas cosas

Comment: Muestra tu código y tus valores de entrada y salida.

Comment: Sisi ahora adjunto mi codigo